# Errors were encountered while processing: intellij-idea-community

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I keep getting this error at the end whenever I try to install any program:

```
Setting up intellij-idea-community (2016.3.4-1) ...    
tar: /opt/ideaIC-*: Cannot open: No such file or directory    
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now    
dpkg: error processing package intellij-idea-community (--configure):    
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2    
Errors were encountered while processing:    
 intellij-idea-community    
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: What commands did you ran, which instructions are you following, where did you get the file you are trying to install?

Comment: The error is clearly this, though: Line 2 `tar: /opt/ideaIC-*: Cannot open: No such file or directory `

Comment: @M.Becerra i am not installing intelli j , i was  installing heroku and node js but at the end i keep getting that error.And i have completely deleted intellij

Comment: Maybe you should have started by writing that on your question. Can you [edit] it to add that the mentioned and also what exactly you did to *completely delete intellij* ?

Comment: @M.Becerra I did this  sudo rm -rf idea-IC-163.12024.1

Comment: And the error message states: `/opt/ideaIC-*... ...No such file`. Did you try to install `intellij` before but cancelled it mid way?

Comment: Run `dpkg --yet-to-unpack` and `dpkg-query --status intellij-idea-community`and [edit] your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with removing `intellij-idea-community`.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run intellij-idea-community
```

Does the `--dry-run` output seem ok? If so run

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq intellij-idea-community
```